# How i can extract TP-LINK firmware from squashfs?

Tags: firmware, mips

I have installed FMK and `binwalk`. FMK have an old `binwalk` that does not work. So, I ran a fresh `binwalk` (from git) as follow:

```
$> binwalk -e wr741ndv4_ru_3_13_2_up_boot(140521).bin
```

And in the directory `_wr741ndv4_ru_3_13_2_up_boot(140521).bin.extracted/`

```
$ls 
120200.squashfs  20400  20400.7z  3CEC  3CEC.7z  squashfs-root  unsquashfs
```

Then I compile `unsquashfs` with `LZMA_XZ_SUPPORT = 1`:

```
$> ./unsquashfs -v 
unsquashfs version 4.2 (2011/02/28)

$> ./unsquashfs -h
SYNTAX: ./unsquashfs [options] filesystem [directories or files to extract]
[...]
Decompressors available:
gzip
lzma
```

Then, I have an error to unpack `squashfs`:

```
$> ./unsquashfs 120200.squashfs
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 1 processor
lzma uncompress failed with error code 9
read_block: failed to read block @0x23d12a
read_fragment_table: failed to read fragment table index
FATAL ERROR aborting: failed to read fragment table
```

What did I do wrong?

P.S. If anyone have unpacked `squashfs` with this version firmware, please share it.

Comment: Specifically for tplink firmware images I had success using **[sasquatch](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch)** than the standard unsquashfs.

Comment: Didn't worked for me TL-WR940N https://www.tp-link.com/de/home-networking/wifi-router/tl-wr940n/ https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201802/20180228/TL-WR940N(EU)_V6_180119.zip

Comment: Something like Linux squashfs-tools would be the typical solution...

Answer (score 1):

Add to option "M"

```
$> binwalk -eM wr741ndv4_ru_3_13_2_up_boot(140521).bin
```

refer)

```
$ man binwalk
```

-M, --matryoshka 
**Recursively scan extracted files**

Comment: Does not work. It's extract old files 120200.squashfs  20400  20400.7z  3D10  3D10.7z  squashfs-root/ and unsquashfs not extracted files from 120200.squashfs